# Limit as x approaches zero.

Tags: limits, trigonometry

$$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\sin(2x)\sin(4x)}{x\sin(3x)}=\frac83$$

I know the answer by the means of Wolfram|Alpha, but I don't know the way there. I have yet to learn L'Hôpital's rule so I cannot apply it. I'm pretty stuck on this one and would appriciate any help given to get me started.

Comment: All you need is $\lim\limits_{x\to 0} \frac{\sin x}{x} = 1$. Do you know that (maybe from the Taylor expansion of $\sin$)?

Comment: @Zanii : I think you should definitely go with Daniel's suggestion.  The limit he quotes can be proven using a geometric argument and the Squeeze Theorem (check your calc book) and does not require Taylor expansions.  I would suggest dividing your numerator and denominator by $x^2$, then splitting your limit into a product and quotient of simpler limits.

Comment: @Zanii : azarel's answer is essentially equivalent to my suggestion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$\frac{\sin 2x\sin 4x}{x\sin 3x}=\frac{2\sin^22x\cos2x}{x(\sin2x\cos x+\sin x\cos 2x)}=\frac2x\frac1{\frac1{\sin2x}+\frac1{4\sin x\cos^2x}}=$$

$$=2\frac1{\frac x{2\sin x}\frac1{\cos x}+\frac x{4\sin x}\frac1{\cos^2x}}\xrightarrow[x\to 0]{}2\frac1{\frac12\cdot 1+\frac14\cdot1}=\frac83$$

We only use basic trigonometric identities, arithmetic of limits and, of course, the fact that

$$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\sin x}x=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac x{\sin x}=1=\lim_{x\to 0}\cos x$$

Answer (score 4):

Observe that 
$$\frac{\sin 2x\sin 4x}{x\sin 3x}=\frac{8}{3}(\frac{\sin 2x}{2x})\cdot(\frac{\sin 4x}{4x})\cdot(\frac{3x}{\sin 3x})$$ 
The limit is clear from that and $\lim_{x\mapsto 0}\frac{\sin x}{x}$.

Answer (score 3):

What are you allowed to use? There are many ways to solve the problem. If you know Maclaurin series expansion, expand each $\sin x$ function: $x+\frac{x^3}{3!} +O(x^5)$ to get the result.

Comment: I have not learned any type of series expansions. I think I might be allowed to use L'Hospital, but it depends on the teachers mood. They can be quite picky.